# How to get my image collections display page to show the first 3 images for each collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4, collections

I've set up a my site so that my users can create individual product collections and add their listings to each collection. I then created a site page that shows all created collections by all users. Right now I have the collection name and the "by so-and-so" displaying there for each collection, all good. I now want to show the first 3 listing images for each collection on top. I am able to get the first 3 images from my listings database to show in each collection using @listings = Listings.all, but that's not correct. But at least that confirms everything connects. I'm having trouble with my controller to def the @listings by 'collection_id'. I've tried so many different variations and the one below is where I'm currently stuck and serves a blank collection and doesn't recognize any/or each collection's listings.

My Pages Controller:

```
@collections = Collection.all.order("created_at DESC")
@listings = Listing.where(collection_id: @collection)
```

My Collections View Page:

```
<% @collections.each do |collection| %>         
    <% @listings.limit(3).each do |listing| %>  
        <%= image_tag listing.image.url(:small) %>
    <% end %>           
<%= collection.name %>
<%= collection.user.business_name %>
<% end %>
```

What am I missing in my controller to get the images to show by :collection_id? Do I need to change anything in my view page? Additionally, is it okay to nest the @listings.limit(3).each within my @collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listing you are querying is not related to the collection, you should do something like this instead

```
<% @collections.each do |collection| %>         
    <% collection.listings.limit(3).each do |listing| %>
```

So you don't need a `@listings` query, but what you need instead is eager loading so you don't keep querying in each loop

```
@collections = Collection.includes(:listings).order(created_at: :desc)
```

If `images` are another object too, then you could include them in the `includes` too

```
@collections = Collection.includes(listings: :images).order(created_at: :desc)
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, I made the changes and am using the first @collections hash above and I'm getting this error: "undefined method `limit' for nil:NilClass". I would like this to work even if a collection only has 1 listing in it and all of my test collections have at least 1 listing. Is this error related to the number of listings per collection I currently have?

Comment: it's kinda weird, because even if the collection has no listings it should return an empty association relation object, what does `collection.listings` return by it self?

Comment: If this belongs in separate question I can do that no problem. But, now I have these 3 images coming in together through <%= image_tag... %>, and I've put that into a div class "frame" and that frame class is styled to be thumbnail size. Is it possible if I want to style only the first image in a div of it's own so that I can size it much larger than the other 2? Again, if this belongs somewhere else, please let me know and I'll re-post.

Comment: yea create a new question with that, it's a styling issue, but if u want a fast answer you could use `cycle`, this is a view helper that cycles through strings when looping